# I have a database and with multiple records of the same date and related amount but I only want a single record and that is date related total amount

Tags: android, sqlite, android-layout, android-cursor

i am using cursor for retrieving data from database but problem is that i have no. of records for same date and i want only one record date wise and related Tamt of date will be added to amount field:

I have database records like :

```
Sr    ExpName       Date       Camt  Tamt
---   --------- -----------   ----- -----
1     Pen        10-10-2012      10    10
2     abc        10-10-2012      30    45
3     xyz        11-10-2012      15    55
4     ggg        11-10-2012      20    75
5     aaa        11-10-2012      10    85
6     nnn        11-10-2012      10    95


 dbhelper = new DbHelper(this);
 db = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor c = db.query(DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, new String[]{"CAST(Date AS DATE)","SUM(Tamt) AS AMT"}, null, null,"CAST(Date AS DATE)", null, null);
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.myrow1, c, new String[]{DbHelper.C_Date,DbHelper.C_Tamt},new int[]{R.id.textView3,R.id.textView5} );
    startManagingCursor(c);     
    lstExpense.setAdapter(adapter);
```

where myrow1 is a layout file in and TextView3 and TextVew5 field where i want to display output DATE and AMOUNT.

And i want ouput like this:

```
DATE             AMOUNT
------------     ------
10-10-2012          40
11-10-2012          35
12-10-2012          10
13-10-2012          10
```

Comment: Read about GROUP BY and aggregation with SUM

Comment: Lets see if i understand that correctly, you want to the sum of Tamt based on the date? is that correct?

Comment: The output you want doesn't seem to match the sample data. The sum of "Camt" for 10-10 is 40, which matches your expected output.  The sum of "Tamt" is 55, which doesn't match expected output, but *does* match  your query. Which is it?

Comment: dear all, i want output like if i have 2 records of same date and also that two records sum of amounts will be appear in one record like  date(1) amount(sum of same date amount)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a problem for [GROUP BY](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#resultset) and the SUM [aggregation function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html).

Working with SQLite directly your query would need to be along the lines of

```
SELECT Date, SUM(Camt) AS Amount FROM Expenses GROUP BY Date;
```

(I've assumed that your database table is called `Expenses`.)

Converting this into an Android cursor query is then pretty simple

```
Cursor c = db.query("Expenses", 
    new String[] { "Date", "SUM(Camt) AS Amount" }, 
    null, null, "Date", null, null, null);
```

That should give you the result that you're looking for.

Comment: shouldn't work properly with adapter..   adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.myrow1, c, new String[]{"Date","Camt"},new int[]{R.id.textView3,R.id.textView5} );